# Crash while trying to launch any application

Tags: android, android-studio, failed-installation

Android studio doesn't launch any application (even new from the studio templates) and fails with the same error:

```
09/29 13:54:36: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.user.myapplication
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.user.myapplication"
Aborted 


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.user.myapplication/com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.user.myapplication/com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.user.myapplication/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.user.myapplication/com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

I tried clean/rebuild, even reinstall studio, but it didn't help.
I can't understand what's happening, please help

Comment: Try restarting studio.

Comment: didn't help, still crushes

Comment: can you post your menifest file?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening....

```
Error: Activity class     {com.example.user.myapplication/com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Your MainActivity class does not exist or something which has been fixed as your **launcher activity**. Check your manifest file. **In your manifest file you have delcared MainActivity as your launcher**
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your manifest on `MainActivity`

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ...
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It says MainActivity does not even exist. Which means, he has already delcared MainActivity as his launcher or he is trying to go to his MainActivity class from any of his other class and, it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio version 2.1 and you enable instant run feature then some times these type error occur.

Clean your project or rebuild then problem resolved. for avoiding this problem disable instant run feature from setting